# System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s) different values for a string on the same computer, different programs

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I'm doing a

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)
```

on a string in two different programs (one console, one web) using .NET 2.0 framework and the encoding is coming back different from the two. For the string "everything" I get the same result, but for the string "OnI3UwUc" I get two different results.

For The "OnI3UwUc", 6f6e693375777563
For the "OnI3UwUc" in another program, I get 4f63493355775563.

In the

I tried to write this to operate the same as some Classic ASP code I have:

```
Dim crypt : Set crypt = CreateObject("Chilkat.Crypt2")      
crypt.UnlockComponent("TXTECHCrypt_6X6EnMdFNRCe") 
crypt.HashAlgorithm = "sha1"  
crypt.CryptAlgorithm = "aes" 
crypt.CipherMode = "ecb" 
crypt.EncodingMode = "hex" 
crypt.SetEncodedKey "100202330405560608790A8B0C9D0EAF","hex"
```

Comment: Would it be asking too much for you to post the two different results you get?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe this. How are you verifying the results of the call?

Comment: Print the results out. If you're using a debugger to look at the results of the call, don't.  It'll mislead you.

Comment: Is the argument actually hardcoded in your program `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OnI3UwUc")` or a variable coming from a poorly coded PHP script POSTing to your web application (hey, I have nothing against PHP btw)? And if you say that it's hardcoded in both programs and producing different byte arrays then we might have a situation to worry about :-) Until then it's ok.

Comment: It's hardcoded and seems to be identical when capital letters aren't used in the one case and different when they are.

Comment: One scenario:5FB7123B47526F7D132B9180C367CE6B82A48452

Comment: Other scenario: 85ACA68713D74B3FA69D2E04B8A811819D8BED79

Comment: @Caveatrob: Neither of those are valid UTF-8. You cannot have received this as output from `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. Maybe there’s a bug in the code you use to turn it into hexadecimal? — The correct UTF-8 for `"OnI3UwUc"` is `4f6e493355775563`.

Comment: Sorry those are the SHA1 hashes of the byte strings

Comment: The code I use for that:using (var sha = SHA1.Create())
   {
    hash = sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
   }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned that the UTF-8 you get from one of the programs is `6f6e693375777563`. This decodes back to `"oni3uwuc"`. In other words, your other program is lowercasing all the letters before UTF-8-encoding them.

Answer (score 0):

That is exceedingly unlikely. Use `File.WriteAllText("C:/file1.txt", s)` for both strings, and compare them carefully. They *will* be different.

In the highly unlikely case that they are actually equal, please try removing *everything* from those two programs that doesn't affect this output, and then post it on connect.microsoft.com, and link here. Note however that programs longer than 100 lines are almost certainly reducible further.